# Read xlsx file using POIFSFileSystem

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to unprotect a protected xlsx file.e.g Book1.xlsx 
Below code runs fine for the first time, Reads Book1.xlsx, decrypt it and again write it to the same filename.

```
public static void unprotectXLSXSheet(String fileName, String password) {
        try{

            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
            Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
            d.verifyPassword(password);
            InputStream is = d.getDataStream(fs);
            System.out.println(is.available());
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(is));
            FileOutputStream fileOut;
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            wb.write(fileOut);
             fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
```

But when the same code tries to access the newly created unprotected Book1.xlsx(or anyother unprotected xlsx file) it fails and showing

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:131)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:104)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:138)
    at com.wolseley.Excel.TestMainDummy.unprotectXLSXSheet(TestMainDummy.java:113)
    at com.wolseley.Excel.TestMainDummy.main(TestMainDummy.java:52)
```

i need help in reading xlsx file and also unlock it using password, as done above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the following line of code doesn't work for Office 2007+ XML documents:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
```

So you'll first need to check the header in the input stream whether it's supported by calling this:

```
POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(is)
```

and only decrypting if the above returns true. The `hasPOIFSHeader` method requires an input stream that supports mark/reset, so check that as well and wrap it in a `PushbackInputStream` if not.

Putting it all together then becomes something like this:

```
public static void unprotectXLSXSheet(String fileName, String password) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        if (!is.markSupported()) {
            is = new PushbackInputStream(is, 8);
        }

        if (POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(is)) {
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
            Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
            d.verifyPassword(password);
            is = d.getDataStream(fs);
        }

        System.out.println(is.available());
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(is));
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
        if (fileOut != null) {
            fileOut.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below old Stack Overflow answer may be help you out from this.

[Reading property sets from Office 2007+ documents with java poi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18635574/2867032)

The class you'll want is POIXMLProperties, something like:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("file.xlsx"));
POIXMLProperties props = new POIXMLProperties(pkg);
System.out.println("The title is " + props.getCorePart().getTitle());
```

From POIXMLProperties you can get access to all the built-in properties, and the custom ones too!